# unstructured data

Tags: json

I have a need to store some data in Salesforce, and be able to access it from other pages and APEX stuff. Basically, the data is JSON. Right now I have APEX code that is attaching it to records as an attachment. Just, throwing the JSON document in as an attachment.

I'd like to do stuff with it. Like run reports. And neat things.

But it has to continue to be unstructured. I can't decompose it into CustomObjects.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this json data inside of a Static Resource, and access it from visualforce, and apex.

You can access a Static Resource from apex using `PageReference.GetContent()`, and you can directly reference a Static Resource in visualforce using `{!Resource.Name}`. [This link](https://www.xgeek.net/en/salesforce/access-static-resources-from-apex-visualforce-and-custom-button/) has code samples for everything youll need to do, and you can find more examples elsewhere.

You wont be able to run reports on data from a Static Resource, or any stored json, without writing some amount of custom code, using reporting apis.